# How to resize a ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, scaling

I have a ScaleDetector in which I zom in my ImageView when it detect a scale movement.
This works, the image is well scaled. 
But the problems is that my ImageView is in a ScrollView, and the ScrollView doesn't resized itself when I scale. So when my imageView is scaled, I can move on it in the first limits of my ScrollView, not beyond.
And of course, the SrollView doestn't have an "setMatrix" or something like that which could allow me to easilly resized it.
So how can I do to resize my ScrollView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution I can think of is, in your java code insert :

```
scroller = (ScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.scroller);
scroller.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Then adjust width and height according to your scale.